# How to send addeventlistener result to html text

Tags: javascript, html

How do I get this javascript to write the results on the webpage as text?

```
document.getElementById("bd").addEventListener("change", function() {
var input = this.valueAsDate;
input.setDate(input.getDate() + 183);
return input;
})
```

Comment: `this` in the provided event handler function refers to `#bd` element.

Comment: You might want to check this out. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/A_first_splash An example that answers your question can be found at the bottom, but there are lots of other answers here to questions you don't know you have yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the value to the text of some element.

```js
document.getElementById("bd").addEventListener("change", function() {
  var input = this.valueAsDate;
  if (input) {
    input.setDate(input.getDate() + 183);
    document.getElementById("result").innerText = input;
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="date" id="bd"> <br>
Date is: <span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.innerHTML = input;
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

This will display the input as html text.
What it is doing is creating a new paragraph DOM element, setting its HTML field and appending it to the body of the HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const date = document.getElementById("bd");
const result = document.getElementById("result")

date.addEventListener("change", onDateChange)

function onDateChange() {
  const input = this.valueAsDate;
  
  if (!input) {
    return addToResults('Invalid date')
  }

  addToResults(input.setDate(input.getDate() + 183));
}

function addToResults(value) {
  result.innerText = String(value)
}
```

```html
<input id="bd" type="date" />
<div id="result"></div>
```